# Twig e Namespaces

Tags: php, twig

Olá, estou com uma dificuldade em implementar o `Twig` no meu projeto `MVC`, estou usando namespaces, autoloader toda aquela coisa do `PSR-0`.
Gostaria da juda de vocês para implementar por que já estou quase surtando. rs

```
public function render($file, $data = null){        
    require_once LIB . '/Twig/Autoloader.php';
    \Twig_Autoloader::register();               

    $loader = new \Lib\Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
    ));
}
```

Essa é meu método que irá renderizar o template, até o momento possuo o seguinte erro:

Exception: `Controller Twig_Autoloader not found. in C:\UwAmp\www\system\engine\autoload.php`

Comment: Se você está usando PSR-0 por que não simplesmente inclui o vendor/autoload.php e dá um use na classe do Twig ?

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, mas ele começa da erro em outras classes dentro do Twig, sei lá o que interface blá blá blá. rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mais fácil vc usar o composer pra fazer o autoload, é só rodar

```
composer require "twig/twig:1.*"
```

e depois incluir o autoload gerado pelo composer:

```
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

O twig tem uma documentação bem completa que explica como fazer a [instalação](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installation) pelo [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)